# Microsoft Webmatrix 2 Beta unable to publish via FTP

Tags: ftp, publishing, webmatrix

Yesterday, I published a project via FTP using webmatrix to my server. I could work remote and all was fine. Today, I wanted to upload some fixes using webmatrix but now it says `Unable to publish the site.`

The log file:

```
18:41:46: Starting publishing using FTP
18:41:46: Connecting to "domain.eu" FTP site. .
18:41:47: Successfully connected to site: "domain.eu".
18:41:47: 221 Goodbye.
18:41:51: Connecting to "domain.eu" FTP site. .
18:41:51: Successfully connected to site: "domain.eu".
18:41:51: Remote file list retrieved. 2 actions, total bytes: 7185.
18:41:51: FTP root folder /httpdocs/application_ is not accessible
18:41:51: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:51: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:52: FTP root folder /httpdocs/DidateImport is not accessible
18:41:52: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:52: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:52: FTP root folder /httpdocs/errors is not accessible
18:41:52: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:52: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:52: FTP root folder /httpdocs/images is not accessible
18:41:52: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:52: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:53: FTP root folder /httpdocs/inc is not accessible
18:41:53: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:53: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:53: FTP root folder /httpdocs/tmp is not accessible
18:41:53: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:53: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:53: FTP root folder /httpdocs/tpl is not accessible
18:41:53: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:53: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:53: FTP root folder /httpdocs/ttf is not accessible
18:41:53: Rebex.Net.FtpResponse
18:41:53: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:41:53: Retrying (1/4)
```

This loops 4 times and at the end of the log comes:

```
18:42:11: /httpdocs: File exists (550).
18:42:11: Unable to publish the site.
18:42:11: 221 Goodbye.
```

I am the only one using this server, there was no reboot, no changes, no other errors. I still can use the FTP account in filezilla and have full access to the files. The `Check Compatibility` shows the same logentries, but the connection test in the settings says it's all OK. I can still use the remote view and edit the files on the fly but it won't let me publish them from my filesystem.

So does anyone knows what went wrong? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: This is pretty strange.  FTP works fine with the same settings in FileZilla and WebMatrix?

Comment: yep, same settings and same account.